# Why does file traversal not working in this PHP file upload code?

Tags: linux, php

I am using this script to upload file to the system with apache2 as server and php7.
If I provide filename as `../../../../tmp/data.png` of uploaded file, then also the file gets uploaded to `/var/up/data.png`.

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $errors = []; // Store errors here                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    $fileName = $_FILES['the_file']['name'];                                                                                                                                                                                          
    $fileSize = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];                                                                                                                                                                                          
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];                                                                                                                                                                                  
    $fileType = $_FILES['the_file']['type'];                                                                                                                                                                                          
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      if ($fileSize > 4000000) {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        $errors[] = "File exceeds maximum size (4MB)";                                                                                                                                                                                
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, "/var/up/". basename($fileName));

        if ($didUpload) {
          echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
          echo "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
        }
      } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
      }

    }
    else{
        echo "Bruhh!";
        }
?>
```

I don't understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script calls [`basename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) on the `$filename` variable, which returns just the file portion and strips out the directory path.

```
$didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, "/var/up/". basename($fileName));
```

So if `$filename` is `../../../fname`, then `basename($filename)` will be `fname`.

Comment: Thanks!
Can it be bypassed anyway?

Comment: @AdityaVerma no, it's a solid protection against path traversal attacks.